# The vs zero article

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, zero-article

> I have to work during church time so I watch ur service on Facebook.

This was a facebook comment from someone to a pastor video.

Why does he say *church time* not *the church time* ? ... because the speaker sure means a specific time for a specific church

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure he means a generic time that church occurs at all churches... generally Sunday morning sometime between 8 am and noon. If someone has to work Sunday mornings, they won't be able to go to a church service at any church at all.

Comment: @Catija thank you so much, so helpful and got your point. I thought in it differently, thank you. But what if he says the church time here .. would that make any sense ??

Comment: The problem with trying to parse Facebook comments is that they're often written very poorly and ungrammatically... see the use of "ur" in this example. Personally, I would never use "the" with church time in this phrase... but I'd also never use the phrase "church time" in the first place...